# Spring CData Flow not create application on PCF dashboard

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-dataflow, pcf

I'm a beginner with Spring Cloud Data Flow and I'have a strange problem with it.
I create a simple "helloworld" cloud Task application and i'm trying to register it using Spring Data Flow.
I pushed the `spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar` into my PCF space setting the following env variable:

```
---
applications:
- name: data-flow-server-personal
  host: data-flow-server-personal
  memory: 1G
  disk_quota: 1G
  instances: 1
  path: ./spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar
  env:
    SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME: data-flow-server
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_URL: https://api.run.pivotal.io
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_ORG: {org}
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SPACE: development
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_DOMAIN: cfapps.io
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_USERNAME: {myPCFUser}
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_PASSWORD: {myPCFPassword}
    SPRING_CLOUD_DEPLOYER_CLOUDFOUNDRY_SKIP_SSL_VALIDATION: true
    SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{"maven": { "remote-repositories": { "repo1": { "url": "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release"} } } }'
```

After that, using the "spring-cloud-dataflow-shell-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar" i registered the "helloWorld" task application using the following command:

```
dataflow:>app register --name myApplication --type task --uri https://github.com/durante-ap/test-job/raw/master/raw/batch-cloud-job-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Successfully registered application 'task:myApplication'
dataflow:>task create helloWorld --definition myApplication
Created new task 'helloWorld'
dataflow:>task launch helloWorld
Launched task 'helloWorld'
dataflow:>task list
╔═══════════?═══════════════?═══════════╗
║Task Name  │Task Definition│Task Status║
╠═══════════?═══════════════?═══════════╣
║helloWorld │myApplication  │COMPLETE   ║
╚═══════════?═══════════════?═══════════╝
```

The task was sucessfully executed, but when i try to see if any application is created into PCF using the command `cf apps` i see only the data-flow-server-personal application

```
    name                      requested state   instances   memory   disk   urls
    data-flow-server-personal started           1/1         1G       1G     data-flow-server-personal.cfapps.io
```

What i missed into the configuration?
I need to see the task application in order to inspect the log of this task using the command

```
cf logs helloWorld
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem!!!
I used the wrong jar `spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar`.
In cloud foundry the jar `spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry-1.6.2.RELEASE.jar` should be used! This is a project designed to PCF

Answer (score 0):

You are using `task` application which is a short-lived one. That means, once the task application completes processing, it no longer exits.

You need to have the `cf logs helloworld` opened before you launch the task to see the logs of this.

Comment: Ok, but if i execute the command `cf logs helloworld` before launching the task by spring-shell, the CF-CLI return me the error `App helloworld not found`. This happens also when i launch the task by spring-shell and after i inspect the log using the command `cf logs helloworld --recent`.

Comment: ok, yeah, but I think you understand the difference as it is expected. Looks like your helloworld application is too fast to get into completion state before you even try opening the log for it. Though this works (as you see the status as `complete` but if you still want to see this working from the log, you could introduce delay in the application at least for the duration by which you can open the log for it.